Failed to check the authorization for topic: The credential information is empty
I am using Pulsar SQL with Presto for querying. I have authorization to view a list of schemas and tables but when querying information from a table the program throws credential information is empty error. Can anyone help me resolve this error?
bash-4.2$ ./pulsar sql  --server http://10.181.169.111:8082 --execute "SHOW CATALOGS";
"pulsar"
"system"


bash-4.2$ ./pulsar sql  --server http://10.181.169.111:8082 --catalog pulsar  --execute "SHOW SCHEMAS";                                 
"tenant/namespace1"

bash-4.2$ ./pulsar sql  --server http://10.181.169.111:8082 --catalog pulsar  --schema "tenant/namespace1" --execute "SHOW TABLES";                     
"presto_sql"


bash-4.2$ ./pulsar sql  --server http://10.181.169.111:8082 --catalog pulsar  --schema "dtenant/namespace1" --execute "SELECT * FROM presto_sql LIMIT 10" --debug;
Query 20240618_215929_00007_w6w8i failed: Failed to check the authorization for topic persistent://tenant/namespace1/presto_sql: The credential information is empty.
io.prestosql.spi.PrestoException: Failed to check the authorization for topic persistent://tenant/namespace1/presto_sql: The credential information is empty.
        at org.apache.pulsar.sql.presto.PulsarAuth.checkTopicAuth(PulsarAuth.java:86)
        at org.apache.pulsar.sql.presto.PulsarMetadata.checkTopicAuthorization(PulsarMetadata.java:431)
        at org.apache.pulsar.sql.presto.PulsarMetadata.getTableHandle(PulsarMetadata.java:133)
        at io.prestosql.plugin.base.classloader.ClassLoaderSafeConnectorMetadata.getTableHandle(ClassLoaderSafeConnectorMetadata.java:190)
        at io.prestosql.metadata.MetadataManager.getTableHandle(MetadataManager.java:320)
        at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.visitTable(StatementAnalyzer.java:1033)
        at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.visitTable(StatementAnalyzer.java:306)
        at io.prestosql.sql.tree.Table.accept(Table.java:53)
        at io.prestosql.sql.tree.AstVisitor.process(AstVisitor.java:27)
        at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.process(StatementAnalyzer.java:323)
        at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.analyzeFrom(StatementAnalyzer.java:2334)
        at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.visitQuerySpecification(StatementAnalyzer.java:1284)
        at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.visitQuerySpecification(StatementAnalyzer.java:306)
        at io.prestosql.sql.tree.QuerySpecification.accept(QuerySpecification.java:144)
        at io.prestosql.sql.tree.AstVisitor.process(AstVisitor.java:27)
        at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.process(StatementAnalyzer.java:323)
        at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.process(StatementAnalyzer.java:333)
        at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.visitQuery(StatementAnalyzer.java:918)
        at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.visitQuery(StatementAnalyzer.java:306)
        at io.prestosql.sql.tree.Query.accept(Query.java:107)
        at io.prestosql.sql.tree.AstVisitor.process(AstVisitor.java:27)
        at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.process(StatementAnalyzer.java:323)
        at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer.analyze(StatementAnalyzer.java:292)
        at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:83)
        at io.prestosql.sql.analyzer.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:75)
        at io.prestosql.execution.SqlQueryExecution.analyze(SqlQueryExecution.java:217)
        at io.prestosql.execution.SqlQueryExecution.<init>(SqlQueryExecution.java:176)
        at io.prestosql.execution.SqlQueryExecution$SqlQueryExecutionFactory.createQueryExecution(SqlQueryExecution.java:705)
        at io.prestosql.dispatcher.LocalDispatchQueryFactory.lambda$createDispatchQuery$0(LocalDispatchQueryFactory.java:121)
        at io.prestosql.$gen.Presto_334____20240618_215045_2.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:131)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:74)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:82)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


I have tried different ways to pass authentication in configuration files but always end up with error.
